# AngularJS directive bindToController with isolate scope using & doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, typescript1.5

I'm using AngularJS 1.4.3 and typescript 1.5

Using a directive I can bind isolate scope properties to a controller using controllerAs and setting `bindToController: true`

But, can I not do the same with expressions?

For instance, something like this works fine:

```
this.scope = {
            name: '@'
        };
```

I can refer to name in my template using the controllerAs name, no problem.

but this doesn't:

```
this.scope = {
            name: '@',
            someMethod: '&'
        };
```

I can't work out a way to call someMethod using the controllerAs syntax.

Are expressions not allowed to be used this way?  The docs don't specify and all the examples I find just repeat the same examples over using @ binding.

I was hoping someMethod would attach to the controller and be usable.

Sort of like this:

```
<div data-my-directive data-some-method="parentCtrl.testMethod(val)"></div>
```

and in my directive

```
public template = "<div ng-click='myController.someMethod({val: 1234})'>NAME: [{{myController.name}}]</div>";
```

Comment: This should work, you might be having some other issues. How does your complete directive defn looks like? Also try to create a demo replicating the issue.

Comment: you might try using `bindToController: true` in your directive definition, which binds your directive scope properties directly to the controller.

Comment: PSL, you are right...turns out it does work, I just didn't realize I had a filter applied in the dev tools console and so I didn't see updates I was expecting.  Sorry, just stupid on my part :)  I'll try and be more careful in the future before posting.

Comment: @Brandon I'm mysteriously having this similar issue.  Not sure if it's my angular version compatibility or what. What was your solution?